# turning rows to columns in Excel

Tags: excel

I have an excel datasheet with more than 1,000,000 rows and 80 columns. the datasheet contains sales information of a chain store with more than 1700 store nationwide. each store is repeated 52(weeks in a year)* about 30 (products sold in that given week)* 2(two years). I want to convert the rows corresponding to products to columns. I can't do that using transverse because the products sold each week might not be exactly the same as those sold next week. do you have any solutions?
 thanks

I just made a very simplified version of that excel file. the problem is that the products sold are not the same each week. there is a limited set of product, but only some of the items are sold each week

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1B2vjIL2hemfQNrCz0X6u_pzi7Euy6IWa3Lj0_HzDXDE

Comment: This does not sound like a job for excel. Do you just need to transpose?

Comment: Hi Mike, please include some sample data if possible.  You don't have to give many rows and columns, just a minimal example which gets the problem across.

Comment: You can't do that period. Excel doesn't have that many columns.

Comment: I just made a very simplified version of that excel file. the problem is that the products sold are not the same each week. there is a limited set of product, but only some of the items are sold each week https://drive.google.com/open?id=1B2vjIL2hemfQNrCz0X6u_pzi7Euy6IWa3Lj0_HzDXDE

Comment: Max columns in Excel 2007 to 2016 is 16,384.  So if you want to transpose, you will also need to break up the data into sets that do not exceed that column limit.

Comment: You see, there are 40 products in total. that means I will have to add 40 columns, which does not exceed the limit you pointed out. However, each week some of these items are sold and some are not. that means the rows do not have a uniform pattern so that I can simply copy - paste(transpose) the data

Comment: Note that the maximum amount of rows is [1,048,576](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3)

Comment: @MikeSal - see my "answer" below and let me know if that's the kind of thing you have in mind.  **If it's not** then you'll need to show an example of what you need the finished data to look like.  There are lots of problem-solvers who enjoy helping you get started, but you end-goal needs to be clarified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't much of an answer yet - but it either will become one or I'll delete it, depending on the OP's response.

---

I'm thinking that transverse/transpose is the wrong term for what you're trying to do.

Perhaps you're just trying to better organize/visualize this data, something similar to one of these **Pivot Tables**:

[image: img]

or

[image: img]

These are just two of the infinite ways you can organize data in a Pivot Table.

Is that similar to what you're trying to do?  If so I'll share some more info.

If this quantity of data is going to keep coming your way, way you really need is to **start using an Access database** to get this under control and be able to report on it properly (and easily, once it's setup).

Comment: Yes. Thank You!! This is what I am looking for. Well, the only difference (which is easily solvable) is that the stores must come as rows and the pivot table must be classical. I guess you first created product columns and assigned each product to its own column and then used pivot table. right?